# Create and use settings module in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python so bear with me. I use the pyDev plugin fore eclipse. There are three files:

**tool.py:**

```
from gui import Tool_Window
import wx
import settings

if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = wx.App()
    Tool_Window(None, settings.WindowHeader)
    window.MainLoop()
```

**Tool_Window.py:**

```
from Tool import settings
import wx

class Tool_Window(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):

    super(Tool_Window,self).__init__(parent, title = title)

    self.SetDimensions(settings.WindowOpenX,
                       settings.WindowOpenY,
                       settings.WindowWidth,
                       settings.WindowHeight)
```

**settings.py:**

```
WindowHeader = 'The SuperAwesome Tool'
WindowOpenX = 500
WindowOpenY = 100
WindowWidth = 200
WindowHeight = 400
```

The "tool.py" file is in a package called "Tool", as is the "settings.py" file, and "Tool_Window" is in the package "gui".

I am getting error messages from a previous file I had in the project, now renamed to the "settings.py". I have tried cleaning the project in Eclipse, but nothing happens. The error message looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oystein/workspaces/python/awesome.tool/src/Tool/tool.py", line 8, in <module>
    Tool_Window(None, settings.WindowHeader)
  File "/home/oystein/workspaces/python/awesome.tool/src/gui/__init__.py", line 12, in __init__
    # ;-)
AttributeError: class GeneralParameters has no attribute 'WindowParameters'
```

Previously I had a class named GeneralParameters with a sub-class WindowParameters, as I wanted to access static variables for settings. I relaized Python couldn't do it like that and changed it to the "settings.py" file.

I run the program from "tool.py"

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the code is running out-of-date bytecode. Remove the `.pyc` files in that directory and rerun your code.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! There was also some trouble with the imports, but that's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: But shouldn't Eclipse/Python build new bytecode files when rerunning the project? I also cleaned the project, but obviously that made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running stale byte-code, remove the `.pyc` files and rerun your code.

The traceback reads the source from the `.py` file but is built from the bytecode, and the fact that is shows that the error is on a line that only consists of a comment is a hint that things are no longer in sync.

Normally, Python will clean up the `.pyc` file when stale, but only if the `.py` modification time is newer.